# Extracting Raw Voice Data from AndroidSmart Phone Microphone

Tags: android, voice

I need to know how to extract raw voice data from android real time. The data should be in time domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/index.html

or

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html